# Haskell writes '\n' instead of a newline

Tags: string, haskell, newline

I have this code and instead of it printing out "\n", I want it to put the next string on a new line, but cannot seem to figure it out. Any pointers?

```
onSeparateLines :: [String] -> String
onSeparateLines [] = ""
onSeparateLines ( x:[] ) = x
onSeparateLines ( x:xs ) = x ++  "\n" ++ onSeparateLines xs
```

what I get is

```
"AAAA\nAAAA"
```

which should be:

```
"AAAA"
"AAAA"
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. We aren't downvoting people just because they don't understand their problem, are we? After all, if they had understood this one then they would have solved it on their own.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs You're entirely right. I suspect it's a spelling thing. I'll fix the title & add a few tags.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Downvote is for useless questions too. I find this question a bit borderline (so I don't downvote it but nor I upvote it).

Answer (score 12):

The given function and your use of "\n" are correct, so the error must be elsewhere. Without knowing the details, I suspect that you are using (the equivalent of) `print` rather than `putStr` to print your string. Make sure that your string is not being `show`n before it is printed.

If this is in GHCi, be aware that values are printed using `print`, so

```
> onSeparateLines ["foo", "bar"]
```

will `print` the string and show escaped characters. You want

```
> putStrLn (onSeparateLines ["foo", "bar"])
```

instead.

Comment: yes that works in the terminal but i need it to do it within the function so all i type is >onSeparateLines` giving `"foo" and on next line "bar"

Comment: I don't know what you're saying. What does "I need to do it within the function" mean? You can't apply `onSeparateLines` to anything other than a list of strings. You have to use Haskell syntax in GHCi so you can't literally type `onSeparateLines "foo" <ENTER> "bar" <ENTER>`.

Comment: the onSeparateLines self defined function needs to work by typing `> onSeparateLines ["foo","bar"]` and nothing else. Then returning `>"foo"` and on the line underneath `"bar"` so the problem is within my code i think. I have tried putting the putStr function within the onSeparateLines function but it just doen't seem to work.

Comment: You can't do that. GHCi will `print` the value. There's no way to prevent that. Your function is correct: it concatenates a list of strings with newlines inbetween. If you include `putStrLn` in the `onSeparateLines` function then it will have a different type. It will be a function `[String] -> IO ()`.

Comment: i could alway define another function that uses `onSeparateLines` and `putStrLn` to do this task I think.

Comment: `onSerparateLines :: [String] -> IO()
     onSerparateLines = mapM_ putStrLn` Is the way to di it people. I got there in the end lol.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've trying to prove '\t' is really a tab. Now I am confident in using it. Thanks again.