# how would I get this function to be accepted with putStr in haskell?

Tags: haskell

how would I get this function to be accepted with putStr in haskell? so it displays each word in a list on a new line??

```
unlines1                 :: [String] -> String
unlines1 [] = []
unlines1 (l:ls) = l ++ (putStr('\n')) : unlines ls
```

Comment: You can't. `putStr` doesn't work that way. The issue is entirely with the way GHCi displays values. The function in your previous question *does* contain a newline between each word.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, what does GHCi have to do with anything?

Comment: @dfeuer This is a follow-up question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155110/haskell-writes-n-instead-of-a-newline?noredirect=1#comment54122817_33155110. The issue is that GHCi is printing the shown value of the string with "\n" escaped.

Comment: so how would i get it to work, i have spent nearly 2 hours trying to fix this

Comment: Your function already works. There is nothing to fix in your code. What I'm trying to fix is your understanding of what is happening. What you are trying to do is impossible. There is literally no way to get a string shown by GHCi as a result of evaluation to not be escaped. That is what GHCi is designed to do, and it is correct that it does so. If you want GHCi to print the string rather than show the result of evaluating it, you must use something like `putStr` to cause GHCi to evaluate and execute the IO action of printing the string.

Comment: oh so because i have defined it as a string the GHCI is just reading the \n as \n and not new line what i need is the IO () that reads \n as new line?

Comment: @symon No, when you write `"abc\ndef"` in  Haskell code you _are_ inserting a newline in the string as in most languages. No difference at all. Try e.g. `length "\n"` which returns 1 and not 2.

Comment: The "issue" is not in the string value. It's just GHCi that, when printing a string value, prefers to turn special characters into source-code syntax. This is so a programmer can clearly see what's inside. If instead one wants to output the string as it is, with no special handling, one uses the `putStr` action. This is however immaterial to the pure function above, which does not have to do anything special: `string1 ++ "\n" ++ string2` simply does the correct thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to be more clear in the larger space provided by an answer.

When you cause GHCi to evaluate a value, e.g.,

```
> "foo"
```

GHCi will attempt to show you that value. It does this by determining whether the type of that value is an instance of `Show`. If it is, GHCi prints the display string that `show` provides for that value. In the case of strings, `show` will escape non-printable characters like `'\n'`. This means that what GHCi actually does is more like:

```
> putStrLn (show "foo")
```

This means that

```
> "foo\nbar"
```

becomes

```
> putStrLn (show "foo\nbar")
```

which, by the definition of `show` for Strings, becomes

```
> putStrLn "foo\\nbar"
```

with the '\n' escaped. This is what GHCi is designed to do. You can't and shouldn't prevent it from doing so.

If, on the other hand, you want to *print* a String, as in *perform the Haskell equivalent of `echo` or `puts` or `printf`*, then you must use an `IO` action to do so. One IO action you can use is `putStr :: String -> IO ()`.

When you evaluate

```
> putStr "foo"
```

GHCi will attempt to evaluate the `IO ()` action and display a result. Because it is an IO action, GHCi is designed to *execute* (perform) the IO for you, in this case printing a string.

So the difference between

```
> "foo\nbar"
```

and

```
> putStr "foo\nbar"
```

is not that the newline is escaped in one string and unescaped in the other. The newline is always a literal newline. The issue is that the former is showing you the inspectable version of the string (with non-printables escaped) and the latter is actually printing the string.

Comment: GHCi actually prefers to use values as `IO` than to show them. If you add `instance Show (IO a) where ...` that won't affect what GHCi does with `IO` actions.

Comment: @dfeuer I could have been more clear about that, thanks.

Comment: something like this: `onSeparateLines1 :: [String] -> IO()
onSeparateLines1 (x:xs) =  putStrLn (show x:"\n")`

Comment: @symon Is that a question?

Comment: If you want a function `[String] -> IO ()` that prints each string on a separate line, `mapM_ putStrLn` is one such function.

Comment: right i have come up wit this : `onSeparateLines1 :: [String] -> IO()
onSeparateLines1 (x:xs) =  (putStrLn  (show x ++ "\n") )` but it stops after printing the first string. I have tried concat in replacement of ++ but the GHCi will not concatenate them.

Comment: You are printing `x`, but you do nothing with the rest of the list (`xs`). I order to do it this way, you will need to know how to use the `Monad` methods. Also, `show` and `++ "\n"` are bot unnecessary: `x` is already a String and `putStrLn` will already add a trailing newline.

Comment: Writing a function `[String] -> IO ()` that prints each string on a separate line is a separate question that has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289779/printing-elements-of-a-list-on-new-lines.

Comment: all that time an it was there but it has been a massive learning cure thanks Rein